# Setting id using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I've been trying to create a menu where after the user clicks on a menu item, that item will be set to active and the previous active item will be deselected. However, I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5M2a/15/

Edit: switched around id and class, though still not sure what's wrong
Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menuOption').mousedown(function() {
          $('#menuOption').attr('class', '');
          $(this).attr('class', 'active');

    });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="side-bar"> 
                <ul class="side-nav">
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li id="menuOption" class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li id="menuOption"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li id="menuOption"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li id="menuOption"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                </ul>   
           </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: IDs must be unique. You can have more than one class per element, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not referencing the element correctly and you should really be adding `classes` not change the `id`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5M2a/13/)

you can also use the `click` call instead of `mousedown`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menuOption').click(function() {
        $('.menuOption').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Element ids should generally be static. Try changing the class instead.

Also, change `mouseOption` to `.menuOption`. Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ByXJc/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menuOption').mousedown(function() {
        $('.menuOption').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('mouseOption')` to `$('.menuOption')`

Other then that you should be never using list element as divider (use CSS instead)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use an extra class for this, as the purpose of [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)s is to give the element a unique identity, not a "state".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mouseOption').mousedown(function () {
        $('.mouseOption').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('mouseOption') doesn't exists!

```
$(".menuOption")
```

which means "select those elements of class menuOption" (point means "class")